# ServiceServer declaration within a class

Tags: c++, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running on Ubuntu 18.04LTS using ROS melodic and kernel 5.0.0-25-generic. I'm currently trying to add a service server to my c++ class. Is this possible?
Should I declare the service inside my class or in the main of the node?

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <armadillo>

// #include <std_msgs/Bool.h>
// #include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <jog_controller/twist_to_jog_frame.h>
#include "jog_msgs/JogFrame.h"
#include "jog_msgs/ControllerStatus.h"
#include "jog_msgs/GetTargetList.h"
#include "jog_msgs/SetTarget.h"

namespace jog_controller
{

TwistToJogFrame::TwistToJogFrame()
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh, pnh("~");
  jog_frame_pub_ = nh.advertise<jog_msgs::JogFrame>("jog_frame", 1);
  // set_target_frame_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame);
  // set_target_link_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("set_target_link", &TwistToJogFrame::setTargetLink, this);
  pnh.getParam("/jog_frame_node/group_names", group_names_);
  pnh.getParam("/jog_frame_node/link_names", link_names_);
  pnh.getParam("group_name", group_name_);
  pnh.getParam("link_name", link_name_);
  pnh.getParam("frame_id", frame_id_);
  pnh.getParam("rotate_axes", rotate_axes_);
  std::string str_rotation_matrix_;
  pnh.getParam("rotation_matrix", str_rotation_matrix_); 
  rotation_matrix_ = arma::mat(str_rotation_matrix_);
  pnh.getParam("dominant_axis_mode", dominant_axis_mode_);
  pnh.getParam("scale_linear", scale_linear_);
  pnh.getParam("scale_angular", scale_angular_);
  pnh.getParam("sub_topic", sub_topic_);
  pnh.getParam("controller_enabled", controller_enabled_);
  twist_sub_ = nh.subscribe(sub_topic_, 10, &TwistToJogFrame::twist_cb, this);
  ros::topic::waitForMessage<geometry_msgs::Twist>(sub_topic_);
}

void TwistToJogFrame::keepOnlyDominantAxis(arma::vec6 &twist_p)
{
  double min = twist_p.min();
  double max = twist_p.max();
  double min_max = max + min;
  if(min_max > 0){
    arma::uword i = twist_p.index_max();
    twist_p.zeros();
    twist_p.at(i) = max;
  } else {
    arma::uword i = twist_p.index_min();
    twist_p.zeros();
    twist_p.at(i) = min;
  }
}

void TwistToJogFrame::rotateAxes(arma::vec6 &twist_p)
{
  arma::vec linear = arma::vec3({twist_p.at(0), twist_p.at(1), twist_p.at(2)});
  arma::vec angular = arma::vec3({twist_p.at(3), twist_p.at(4), twist_p.at(5)});

  linear = rotation_matrix_ * linear;
  angular = rotation_matrix_ * angular;

  //Write in original vector
  for(arma::uword i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
    twist_p[i] = linear[i];
    twist_p[i+3] = angular[i];
  }
}

bool TwistToJogFrame::hasDuplicate(const arma::vec6 &twist_p)
{
  arma::vec nz_tmp = arma::nonzeros(twist_p);
  arma::vec unique_tmp = arma::unique(nz_tmp);
  return size(unique_tmp) != size(nz_tmp);
}

void TwistToJogFrame::scaleCommand(arma::vec6 &twist_p)
{
  for(arma::uword i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    twist_p.at(i) = twist_p.at(i) * scale_linear_;
  }
  for(arma::uword i = 3; i < 6; i++)
  {
    twist_p.at(i) = twist_p.at(i) * scale_angular_;
  }
}

void TwistToJogFrame::twist_cb(const geometry_msgs::TwistConstPtr &twist)
{
  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex_);

  // publish
  jog_msgs::JogFrame msg;
  msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  msg.header.frame_id = frame_id_;
  msg.group_name = group_name_;
  msg.link_name = link_name_;

  arma::vec6 v_twist = arma::vec6({twist->linear.x, twist->linear.y, twist->linear.z, twist->angular.x, twist->angular.y, twist->angular.z});

  if(dominant_axis_mode_)
  {
    if(hasDuplicate(v_twist))
    {
      v_twist.zeros(); //handling the edge case
    } else {
      keepOnlyDominantAxis(v_twist);
    }
  }
  
  if(rotate_axes_)
  {
    rotateAxes(v_twist);
  }

  scaleCommand(v_twist);

  msg.avoid_collisions = true;

  // Publish if the button is enabled
  if(controller_enabled_)
  {
    // Publish only if at least one of the commands is different from zero.
    if(arma::any(v_twist))
    {
      //Adding linear and angular values to the msg.
      msg.linear_delta.x = v_twist.at(0);
      msg.linear_delta.y = v_twist.at(1);
      msg.linear_delta.z = v_twist.at(2);
      msg.angular_delta.x = v_twist.at(3);
      msg.angular_delta.y = v_twist.at(4);
      msg.angular_delta.z = v_twist.at(5);

      jog_frame_pub_.publish(msg);
    }
  }  
  }  

bool TwistToJogFrame::getTargetFrameList(jog_msgs::GetTargetListRequest &req, jog_msgs::GetTargetListResponse &res){
  res.target = link_names_;
  return true;
}

// //callback for controller_enable service
bool TwistToJogFrame::setControllerStatus(jog_msgs::ControllerStatusRequest &req)
{
  controller_enabled_ = req.status;
  return true;
}

bool TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest &target_frame)
{
  frame_id_ = target_frame.name;
  return true;
}

bool TwistToJogFrame::setTargetLink(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest &target_link)
{
  link_name_ = target_link.name;
  return true;
}

}  // namespace jog_controller

/**
 * @brief Main function of the node
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "twist_to_jog_frame");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame node;
  
  ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);

  ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
  while ( ros::ok() )
  {
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors when I try to compile this I get the following errors:

```
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: error: no matching function for call to ‘ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const char [17], bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest&), jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*)’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:879:17: note: candidate: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), T*)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), T *obj)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:879:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:924:17: note: candidate: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), T*)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(T::*srv_func)(ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), T *obj)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:924:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>’ and ‘jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest {aka jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:970:17: note: candidate: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(MReq&, MRes&), const boost::shared_ptr<X>&)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(T::*srv_func)(MReq &, MRes &), const boost::shared_ptr<T>& obj)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:970:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1017:17: note: candidate: template<class T, class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (T::*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), const boost::shared_ptr<X>&)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(T::*srv_func)(ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&), const boost::shared_ptr<T>& obj)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1017:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>’ and ‘jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest {aka jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1061:17: note: candidate: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (*)(MReq&, MRes&))
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(*srv_func)(MReq&, MRes&))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1061:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘bool (*)(MReq&, MRes&)’ and ‘bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest&) {aka bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >&)}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1104:17: note: candidate: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, bool (*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&))
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, bool(*srv_func)(ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1104:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘bool (*)(ros::ServiceEvent<MReq, MRes>&)’ and ‘bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest&) {aka bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >&)}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1145:17: note: candidate: template<class MReq, class MRes> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>& callback,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1145:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::function<bool(MReq&, MRes&)>’ and ‘bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest&) {aka bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >&)}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1190:17: note: candidate: template<class S> ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(const string&, const boost::function<bool(S&)>&, const VoidConstPtr&)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(const std::string& service, const boost::function<bool(S&)>& callback,
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1190:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:176:158: note:   mismatched types ‘const boost::function<bool(S&)>’ and ‘bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest&) {aka bool (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::*)(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest_<std::allocator<void> >&)}’
   ros::ServiceServer srv = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, (jog_controller::TwistToJogFrame*) &node);
                                                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from /opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/ros.h:45:0,
                 from /home/alex/Code/ovis_ws/src/jog_control/jog_controller/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp:1:
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1222:17: note: candidate: ros::ServiceServer ros::NodeHandle::advertiseService(ros::AdvertiseServiceOptions&)
   ServiceServer advertiseService(AdvertiseServiceOptions& ops);
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/node_handle.h:1222:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
jog_control/jog_controller/CMakeFiles/twist_to_jog_frame.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'jog_control/jog_controller/CMakeFiles/twist_to_jog_frame.dir/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [jog_control/jog_controller/CMakeFiles/twist_to_jog_frame.dir/src/twist_to_jog_frame.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7300: recipe for target 'jog_control/jog_controller/CMakeFiles/twist_to_jog_frame.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [jog_control/jog_controller/CMakeFiles/twist_to_jog_frame.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346280/serviceserver-declaration-within-a-class/) by [LazyEngineerToBe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52359/lazyengineertobe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found why I got this error. My service wasn't defined properly. The response parameter is required even if not used.

```
bool TwistToJogFrame::setTargetLink(jog_msgs::SetTargetRequest &target_link, jog_msgs::SetTargetResponse &res)
{
  link_name_ = target_link.name;
  return true;
}
```

I then added the service server to the class

```
TwistToJogFrame::TwistToJogFrame()
{
  ros::NodeHandle nh, pnh("~");
  jog_frame_pub_ = nh.advertise<jog_msgs::JogFrame>("jog_frame", 1);
  get_target_frame_list_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("get_target_frame_list", &TwistToJogFrame::getTargetFrameList, this);
  set_controller_status_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("set_controller_status", &TwistToJogFrame::setControllerStatus, this);
  set_target_frame_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("set_target_frame", &TwistToJogFrame::setTargetFrame, this);
  set_target_link_srv_ = nh.advertiseService("set_target_link", &TwistToJogFrame::setTargetLink, this);
  pnh.getParam("/jog_frame_node/group_names", group_names_);
  pnh.getParam("/jog_frame_node/link_names", link_names_);
  pnh.getParam("group_name", group_name_);
  pnh.getParam("link_name", link_name_);
  pnh.getParam("frame_id", frame_id_);
  pnh.getParam("rotate_axes", rotate_axes_);
  std::string str_rotation_matrix_;
  pnh.getParam("rotation_matrix", str_rotation_matrix_); 
  rotation_matrix_ = arma::mat(str_rotation_matrix_);
  pnh.getParam("dominant_axis_mode", dominant_axis_mode_);
  pnh.getParam("scale_linear", scale_linear_);
  pnh.getParam("scale_angular", scale_angular_);
  pnh.getParam("sub_topic", sub_topic_);
  pnh.getParam("controller_enabled", controller_enabled_);
  twist_sub_ = nh.subscribe(sub_topic_, 10, &TwistToJogFrame::twist_cb, this);
  ros::topic::waitForMessage<geometry_msgs::Twist>(sub_topic_);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [LazyEngineerToBe](https://answers.ros.org/users/52359/lazyengineertobe/) with karma: 91 on 2020-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0